# Creating local image of my AWS (Amazon) website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have an Amazon hosted website including EC2 and RDS services.
I would like to shut it down, but before that backup everything so in the future I'll be able to restore it without hassle.
Is there an easy way to do that and refrain from charges while it is not active?

Preferred way would be to download the files locally to my PC.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to shut down the server such that it is easy to restore in the future is to create a snapshot of the server in AWS using the AWS Browser UI.  That way, you can keep the complete state of the server stored in Amazon's S3 storage system.  While that still costs a little bit of money, it is literally pennies to perhaps a few dollars a month for most systems (the cost depends on the amount of storage in total).

If you want to completely shut down your AWS account (or at least not pay any fees), you can certainly backup all of your data.  You would still need to rebuild the server following that strategy.

There is a new service called [Ravello](http://www.ravellosystems.com/) (now in public beta) that makes it easy to move images between various cloud platforms, including e.g. VMWare on your own PC.  I'm aware that you can create an image locally and then move it into AWS.  The other direction may well work as well.

Comment: As the original question also was about RDS: for the database you would still have to do a normal `mysqldump`, you can restore it anywhere.